# Empty partition window when installing leads to "no root file system is defined"

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I downloaded the 18.04 ISO from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

I transferred the ISO to a USB

When I restart my computer, the installer loads up.

I am able to:

- Select my language and click "Install Ubuntu"
- connect to my WIFI network
- Tell Ubuntu to install additional updates

**Problem**

When I get to the screen with the partition table, the table is blank.

The field below it that says "Device for boot loader install:" is filled in with `/dev/sda` and no other options are available.

If I click continue I get an error saying "No root partition is defined" (duh) and If I click one of the +/-/change buttons, the page basically becomes unresponsive, although I can move the mouse.

[This install process](https://ivanblagojevic.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-lts-on-an-empty-hard-disk-tutorial/) is identical to mine, except mine completely skips step 5. This must be causing the problem

Clicking the **Try Ubuntu** option does work as expected.

I have checked the disk for errors and there were none.

I have done a memory test and no errors were found.

I also performed a secure erase on my hard drive, thinking it might fix the problem. It did not.

I also tried clearing meta data with the following command:

```
sudo dmraid -Er /dev/sda
```

That didn't work either.

Nothing seems to work.

Edit: I am using a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 currently installed

Comment: You forgot to set `root` partition. Are you sure you have created a new partition, format it and set it as `root`?

Comment: Are  you sure Windows fast start up is off? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Windows will also turn it on with updates. If UEFI:   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it turned out to be an erroneous BIOS setting.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Had to switch to AHCI in my BIOS.

Comment: shouldn't that be AHCI? I'd edit, but I'm not 100% sure!